# Can we find $\mu<\kappa$ with $2^{\mu^{(n)}}<\sup_{n<\omega}\mu^{(n)}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

Let $\kappa$ be inaccessible. Can we find $\mu$ with $cf(2^\mu)<\kappa$ and $2^{\mu^{(n)}}<\sup_{n<\omega}\mu^{(n)}$ for every $n<\omega$?

Comment: What does $\mu^{(n)}$ mean? I'm not familiar with this notation.

Comment: @AlexKruckman $\mu^{(0)}=\mu$ and $\mu^{(n+1)}=(\mu^{(n)})^+$.

Comment: With the continuum hypothesis, this amounts to finding $\mu$ such that $cf(2^\mu) < \kappa$. But this is easy since $\kappa$ is regular and strong limit. So you can not disprove the existence of such a $\mu$

Comment: The standard notation for the $n$th successor is $\mu^{+n}$.

Comment: Also, what does the inaccessible cardinal have to do with this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I need it to find a normal ultrafilter (in Karel Prikry's On descendingly complete ultrafilters, theorem 2c, says we can find a normal ultrafilter under these and other conditions).

Comment: @edgaralonso You'll need a measurable cardinal for that, not just an inaccessible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the notation correctly, if $\mu = \aleph_\alpha$, then $\mu^{(n)} = \aleph_{\alpha+n}$ and $\sup_{n<\omega}\mu^{(n)}$ is $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$. So you're asking for some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $2^{\aleph_{\alpha+n}} < \aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$ for all $n\in \omega$, which is equivalent to the condition that $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$ is a strong limit cardinal.

You also ask that $cf(2^{\aleph_\alpha})<\kappa$ for some fixed inaccessible $\kappa$. I'm not sure what the role of this condition is, since $\kappa$ doesn't appear in the rest of the statement. Why not just ask about the first inaccessible? And in any case, if $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$ is a strong limit, then since $\aleph_\alpha < 2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} < \aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$, we have that $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}$ is a successor cardinal, hence regular, so $cf(2^{\aleph_{\alpha}})$ is just $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}$. And again, if $2^{\aleph_\alpha}<\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$, then $\aleph_\alpha<\kappa$ iff $2^{\aleph_\alpha}<\kappa$ (since if $\aleph_\alpha<\kappa$, then certainly $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}\leq\kappa$).

So your question can be rephrased: Can we find $\mu = \aleph_{\alpha}<\kappa$ such that $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$ is a strong limit?

The existence of such a $\mu$ is independent from ZFC. Indeed, by [Easton's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easton%27s_theorem), it's consistent that $2^{\aleph_{\alpha+1}} = \aleph_{\alpha+\omega+1}$ for every ordinal $\alpha$ (since both these cardinals are successors, and hence regular), in which case no cardinal of the form $\aleph_{\alpha+\omega}$ is a strong limit. On the other hand, under GCH, *every* infinite cardinal $<\kappa$ works, since every limit cardinal is a strong limit cardinal.